# Is it possible to publish a library without giving clients access to the source code?

Tags: android

I want my clients to not be able to see the source code of my library and instead work with APIs. Is there a way for Android Studio Reach to source code without showing it to the clients? 
Is the highlighted line in [jitpack privacy documentation](https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/), the same thing I'm looking for?

[jitpack documentation pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUW9T.png)

Comment: Just publish the aar in a maven repo without source code

Comment: source code is accessible by reverse engineering. I want my clients to be able to import my Android library without the possibility for them to have access to the source code of that library.

Comment: You have to obfuscate the code in aar. You have to use something like DexGuard (it is not free).

Comment: obfuscating does not work that well in java... good decompilers always get good enough code to reproduce the original intent. Maybe just live with it, or use a real compiled language, or expose a webservice instead of a library (and the lib you release is only the connect to the webservice) - or go full open source